# How to write an openHAB rule which increments a number?

Tags: openhab

I want to write a Rule in openHAB2, which increments a counter of all group items.
The items:

```
Group counters
Number cnt1 (counters)
Number cnt2 (counters)
```

My try of a rule:

```
rule "Increase value .1 per minute"
when 
    Time cron "0 * * * * ?" or
    System started
then
    // Initialize. Necessary?
    counters?.members.forEach(counter|
        postUpdate(counter, 0.0)
    )
    counters?.members.forEach(counter|
        postUpdate(counter, 0.1 + counter.state)
    }
end
```

But that does not work. Exception:

`Error during the execution of startup rule 'Increase value .1 per minute': Could not invoke method: org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.DoubleExtensions.operator_plus(double,byte) on instance: null`

I tried to explore the type of counter.state, and with `logInfo(counter.state.class)` it correctly logs `...DecimalType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the implicit type casting doesn't seem to work. If you'd change the rule to something like:

```
rule "Increase value .1 per minute"
when 
    Time cron "0 * * * * ?" or
    System started
then
    // Initialize. Necessary?
    counters?.members.forEach(counter|
        if (counter.state == null) {
            postUpdate(counter, 0.0)
        }
    )
    counters?.members.forEach(counter|
        postUpdate(counter, 0.1 + (counter.state as DecimalType))
    }
end
```

it should work. Hope this helps,

Thomas E.-E.